# AQTime is not identifying my application's debug information

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, aqtime

I am facing a strange issue with AQTime in a Delphi XE application.

I am trying to run AQTime for performance improvement but due to this issue I can't do so.

In Module Panel, application is marked with **No Debug Info**.
When I try to run the application, I get a message saying **There is no code selected for profiling**.

[image: AQTIME Screen]

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Wow, AQTime, I haven't seen that tool in years, I didn't know it was still around.

Comment: @rem It is still there with Delphi IDE :)

Comment: Related: [Compiled with debug info but AQtime says "No Debug Info"](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/AQtime/Compiled-with-debug-info-but-AQtime-says-quot-No-Debug-Info-quot/td-p/78220) and [How AQTime Profilers Use Metadata and Debug Information](https://support.smartbear.com/aqtime/docs/profiling-with/prepare-apps/debug-info.html) and especially [Compiler Settings for Embarcadero Delphi XE](https://support.smartbear.com/aqtime/docs/profiling-with/prepare-apps/compiler-settings-native/delphi/delphi-xe.html)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the links. I already tried all these except support ticket.
Creating a new support ticket now. I appreciate your efforts for me. Thanks